# Non-additivity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and consider the following random variable
\begin{equation}\mathsf{X}:\Omega\mapsto \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R}^n)\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the set of all the finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. the random variable is a set of random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whos cardinality is also random.
Now consider the following function
\begin{equation}\beta_\mathsf{X}(S)\triangleq \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{X}\subset S)\end{equation}
defined over the open subsets $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
For the sake of clarity
\begin{equation}\mathsf{X}\subset S \triangleq \{\omega \in \Omega: \mathsf{X}(\omega)\subset S\}\end{equation}

Then this function $\beta_\mathsf{X}(\cdot)$ is not additive, i.e.
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\beta_\mathsf{X}(S_1 \cup S_2)\neq \beta_\mathsf{X}(S_1)+\beta_\mathsf{X}(S_2)\end{equation}
even when $S_1\cap S_2 =\varnothing$. How can I show this fact? Maybe is sufficient a counterexample, i.e. a simple couple of sets $S_1$, $S_2$ and a random finite set $\mathsf{X}$ such that $(1)$ holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega=\{0\}$, $X(0)=\{1,2\}$. Then $\beta_X((0,3))\neq \beta_X((0,2))+\beta_X((1,3))$.

Comment: @P.Quinton: I missed the requirement that $S$ be open. It's fixed now.